# Cookie Store Alternative for Firefox and Safari Browsers

Tags: javascript, cookies

At present I am looking to capture expiry date for cookies on the browser.

These are cookies set by others and I can't change it. Just looking to read the cookie and it's expiry.

The following works for Chrome and Edge.

```
cookieStore.get('myCookie')
    .then(cookie => cookie.expiry)
    .then(expiry => console.log(expiry))
```

But this is not supported in Firefox and Safari as mentioned here under browser compatibility.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CookieStore

Are there alternatives, work arounds for Firefox and Safari to achieve the same?

Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: You were already told in your previous question that there's no portable way to do this. Why do you think asking again will produce a different answer?

Comment: What are you doing that needs to read cookies set by others, anyway?

Comment: @Barmar The previoud question was closed pointing me to the same question I referenced before. This is a different question. I am looking for alternatives for cookieStore.

Comment: @Barmar Using that cookie value to extract some other data that corresponds to it. But only want to do that if the cookie's expiry is under a certain period of time. Thus looking to see the cookie's expiry date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least one polyfill library for the cookieStore API : https://github.com/markcellus/cookie-store

I guess a polyfill qualifies as a workaround but note that there is a warning:

```
EXPERIMENTAL: The Cookie Store API is not a W3C standard yet and the final implementation may differ from the current API of this project.
```

You may already know it but some cookies are http-only and you may not have access to them from client side javascript.